# Why do I keep getting variable x not initialized?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

My second line of code is where I declare the data type. In my second else if statement I try to initialize my variable using other variables that all ready hold value.

```
    int items;
    double itemPrice, discountR, totalCost,discountCost, x; 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity of the item: -->");
    items = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the price of an item: -->");
    itemPrice = scan.nextDouble();
```

I make a scanner and declare my inputs.

```
    if(items <= 0 || itemPrice <= 0)
    System.out.print("Error: Input must be greater than zero");

    else if(items <= 9)
    { 
    totalCost = itemPrice;   
    discountR = 0;
    System.out.print("Your total cost is "+ totalCost);
    System.out.print("Your discount rate is "+ discountR);
    System.out.print("Discount amount is $O");
    System.out.print("The net amount is "+ itemPrice);
    }
```

First test everything works

```
    else if(items >= 10 && items <= 19)
    {
    discountR = 0.1;
    itemPrice * discountR = x; **Where the problem occurs**
    System.out.print("Your total cost is "+ totalCost);
    System.out.print("Your discount rate is "+ discountR);
    System.out.print("Discount amount is $O");
    System.out.print("The net amount is "+ itemPrice);
    }
```

Comment: Because you haven't initialized it? (Your `if` statements don't cover every possible case.)

Comment: @chrylis What do I do to fix it? I tried the same thing outside of the if statement. Still doesn't work. Also how come I was allowed to initialize discount individually rate in my if statement but not x?

Answer (score 1):

```
itemPrice * discountR = x; **Where the problem occurs**
```

change it to:

```
x = itemPrice * discountR;
```

Comment: @Quinten LeRoy Williams  Did this solve the Issue? I seems like you just mixed up the order of this value-assignment.